# java communication with NFC (PC/SC)

Tags: java, linux, nfc, pcsc

Is there a way to java recogonize my NFC card reader with `javax.smartcardio.TerminalFactory`?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and with `pcsc_scan` I able to read the card:

```
Reader 0: SCL010 Contactless Reader [SCL010 Contactless Reader] (21160951211983) 00 00
  Card state: Card inserted, 
  ATR: 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A

  ATR: 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
+ TS = 3B --> Direct Convention
+ T0 = 8F, Y(1): 1000, K: 15 (historical bytes)
  TD(1) = 80 --> Y(i+1) = 1000, Protocol T = 0 
-----
  TD(2) = 01 --> Y(i+1) = 0000, Protocol T = 1 
-----
+ Historical bytes: 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00
  Category indicator byte: 80 (compact TLV data object)
    Tag: 4, len: F (initial access data)
      Initial access data: 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00
+ TCK = 6A (correct checksum)

Possibly identified card (using /usr/share/pcsc/smartcard_list.txt):
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 .. 00 01 00 00 00 00 ..
    Mifare Standard 1K (as per PCSC std part3)
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 .. .. 00 00 00 00 ..
    RFID - ISO 14443 Type A Part 3 (as per PCSC std part3)
3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 01 00 00 00 00 6A
```

But with

```
CardTerminals terminals = TerminalFactory.getDefault().terminals();
List<CardTerminal> list = terminals.list();
```

always return an empty `list`

It is a driver problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just run the program with `-Dsun.security.smartcardio.library=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcsclite.so.1` and worked!

Comment: And of course change the path of the libpcsclite.so.1 according to your system. By the way you save me a lot of time, thanks! :)